# FPV system for ground vehicle

Tags: first-person-view

Is there a VR goggle system with remote control made for ground vehicles? Drones have a clear line of sight, so I would imagine the same system would barely work on ground? I need up to 200 metres of distance - there would be a few obstacles. Is there such a system? I would need basic control inputs - analog up/down and left/right. And, most importantly, clear video signal in VR. Price is not an issue.

Comment: Well, any radio system will struggle in dense areas... what kinds of obstacles do you have in mind for the video link to deal with?

Comment: trees, cars, etc. it wouldn't be something through buildings - mainly in open air with possibility to go around the corner

Answer (score 2):

Lower frequency = better penetration*

A 900 or 433MHz control link (DragonLink is the only plug-and-play 433 I know of off-hand) will penetrate quite well, and has impressive range with direct line of sight.

1200MHz (1.2GHz) video systems are available. Standard receiver modules for goggles are also available so that these can be drop-in solutions for existing equipment.

Ground vehicles have the advantage of (hopefully) maintaining a consistent orientation, so antenna placement is much easier. Everything can be done vertically polarized, and at lower frequencies, multipath interference is less of an issue. Linear directional antennas can have very high gains if desired.

*MIMO systems may be able to catch non-Fresnel reflection paths and work with them, however at the expense of latency and with greater processing. Analog video systems are not MIMO, but some digital systems such as DJI likely are. In this case higher frequencies can actually be advantageous as there is more likely a reflected path.